# Creating a core dump on clr exception thrown

Tags: c#, debugging, clr, windbg, dump

I'm trying to create a dump using windbg every time a **specific** clr exception is THROWN.

I know about !soe, but I don't want the execution to stop, I just want it to create a dump.

Is this possible?

If it's not possible using windbg, I'm also open to other recommendations on how to achieve this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [procdump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx). Maybe use the option "-e 1" to capture a dump on first-chance exceptions.

Edit:

For specific exceptions, you may need ADPlus. See this [post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163530.aspx) for example.

More edits:

Also possible without ADPlus: In Windbg -> Debug -> Event Filters, set CLR exception to **ignored - not handled**. Click the Commands button and then enter the following (with your particular exception type of course):

```
!soe  System.ArgumentNullException 1;.if(@$t1==0) {g} .else {.dump /ma /u d:\ANE.dmp}
```

Comment: Thanks, I might have not made myself clear - when I said 'exception of some sort' I meant a specific exception, and not when any exception is thrown. I don't think that's possible with procdump

Comment: @RoyReznik ADPlus may be what you need. Please follow the link in my edited answer.

Comment: ADPlus worked, but newer version require a little different syntax than the post you referenced to. I suggest whoever wants to use it should go to http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/315536/Adplus-handling-managed-exceptions

Answer (score 1):

In WinDbg, 'Debug > Event Filters', find the specifc exception you want to execute a command for or add a numbered exception.

Then click 'Commands' and enter:

```
.dump /ma c:\mydump.dmp
```

in the command box, you can even enter a second command for second chance exception handling and this will write a full mini-dump when the exception event is triggered.